# not able to select the data from a table in hive

Tags: hive

When I try to create a table in hive, I am getting `OK`, and getting `OK` while I insert the values through a text file. But while selecting the values from that table I am getting the below error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.unset(Ljava/lang/String;)
```

Comment: version of hadoop?

Comment: I am using 1.2.1. As suggested by you, I will try installing the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the version inconsistencies, you need to switched to newer version of hadoop 2.X.x.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842004/issue-in-apache-hive-0-14-running-dml-queries

you can check which version of hadoop will work with which version of hive - [from hive download page](https://hive.apache.org/downloads.html)